# Why does perf show less floating point events than expected?

Tags: c, linux, perf

I'm writing a C program that does a 50x50 matrix multiplication.

I compiled it to assembly and I see it has at least 2 floating point instructions (mulsd and addsd) in the most inner loop. The loop is executed 125000 times, so I was expecting `perf stat` to give me at least 250000 floating point operations counted.

However when I run the following command,

```
perf stat -e r530110 -e r531010 -e r532010 -e r534010 -e r538010 ./matmul
```

I only get the following counts

```
           448 r530110                                                     
             0 r531010                                                     
             0 r532010                                                     
             0 r534010                                                     
 <not counted> r538010                 

   0.001082287 seconds time elapsed
```

My compiler does not produce SSE instructions so the other zero counts are expected. However, I only got 448 floating point operations.

What is happening?

Comment: Please produce a minimal example and give us the assembly code. If you do so, you will likely answer your own question.

Comment: Also make titles more precise: what is "suspicious"? :-) I tried editing it to improve.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 Thanks for editing! :-) I've figured out the problem. It was a noob misunderstanding.

Comment: Your title says "floating point **exceptions**".  Do you mean the x87 concept, a language concept (but C doesn't have them), or was that just a typo?

Comment: @BenVoigt That was edited by another user. I forgot to correct it. I meant floating point event. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. I misunderstood: `mulsd` and `addsd` are actually SSE instructions.

The stat `r530110` (FP_COMPS_OPS_EXE:X87) does not count `mulsd` or `addsd`.

I needed to look at `r538010` (FP_COMPS_OPS:SSE_SCALAR_DOUBLE).

My guess for the reason those were `<not counted>` in my program was because the program finished too quickly. When I increased the size of the matrix (so the program runs longer), the floating point event count came out correct.